# Can I resize a TikZ picture to have certain dimensions (width, height)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling, width, standalone, height

Suppose that I have made a`TikZ` picture using the  `standalone` class, is there an easy way to determine some fixed output dimension of this picture, say `width=16cm, height=12cm`? This could be useful in the case I want to export this picture to a presentation, which only accepts PNG, hence when I need to convert the vector image to a raster image.

Example code of one of my TikZ pictures:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-network}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]

\Vertex[x=0,y=1,label=\textbf{Genesis},shape=rectangle,size=3,color=blue!80!black,Math,fontsize=\large]{G1}

\Vertex[x=6,y=1,label=\textbf{Block 1},size=3,shape=rectangle,color=orange,Math,fontsize=\large]{b1}
\Text[x=0,y=0.5]{Index:0}
\Text[x=0,y=0]{Hash:a0}
\Vertex[x=12,y=1,label=\textbf{Block 2},size=3,shape=rectangle,color=orange,Math,fontsize=\large]{b2}
\Text[x=6,y=0.5]{Index:1}
\Text[x=6,y=0]{Hash:eaKvl}
\Vertex[x=18,y=1,label=\textbf{Block 3},size=3,shape=rectangle,color=orange,Math,fontsize=\large]{b3}

\Text[x=12,y=0.5]{Index:2}
\Text[x=12,y=0]{Hash:yezgLg1}

\Text[x=18,y=0.5]{Index:3}
\Text[x=18,y=0]{Hash:adLc2eZ}
\Edge[Direct=True,color=black,lw=2,bend=0](G1)(b1)
\Edge[Direct=True,color=black,lw=2,bend=0](b1)(b2)
\Edge[Direct=True,color=black,lw=2,bend=0](b2)(b3)

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example of the generated image]

Comment: After you had created the `foo` picture using `standalone` you can insert the pdf output using `\includegraphics[width=4cm]{foo.pdf}` in your main file.

Comment: You can also use \resizebox (documentation in graphicx package, already loaded).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! All you need to do is to add `transform shape` to the options of the `tikzpicture` to make the transformations "active".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to create PNGs from your `standalone` file in a certain size, you can use the `png` class option to do this. It has a `size` and a `density` option to select the resulting image size. The `density` option is AFAIK the important one here.

From the `standalone` v1.2 manual, page 17:

> `density`: Sets the density in dots-per-inch (dpi). Can be a single
>   numerical value or ‘〈X〉x〈Y〉’. Default: 300
>   `size`: Sets the size of
>   the image. Can be a single numerical value or ‘〈X〉x〈Y〉’. If empty the
>   size is determined by the density setting and the size of the PDF.
>   Default: empty

It's used like `\documentclass[png={size=...,density=...}]{standalone}`.

---

Otherwise if you want to resize the picture for any other reason to a certain width and height you can just use the `adjustbox` package around the `tikzpicture`. Note that you need then remove the `tikz` option of the `standalone` class, otherwise every (outer) `tikzpicture` will be turned into a page automatically, which clashes with the surrounding environment then.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{width=16cm, height=12cm, keepaspectratio}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (5,5) {some tikz content} ;
\draw (0,0) -- (10, 10);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}%

\end{document}
```

---

If you have the need of multiple pages in the document use the `multi=ENVIRONMENTNAME` class option and wrap each one in that environment as mentioned in the manual. Note that the `tikz` option is just short for `multi=tikzpicture` and also loads the `tikz` package for you.

```
\documentclass[multi=PAGE]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{PAGE}%
\begin{adjustbox}{width=16cm, height=12cm, keepaspectratio}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (5,5) {some tikz content} ;
\draw (0,0) -- (10, 10);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}%
\end{PAGE}

\begin{PAGE}%
\begin{adjustbox}{width=16cm, height=12cm, keepaspectratio}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (5,5) {some other tikz content} ;
\draw (0,10) -- (10, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}%
\end{PAGE}

\end{document}
```